# How to get useful stack traces from webpack-based, karma (Jasmine) tests for angular?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, webpack, karma-runner

I'm using a webpack-based angular project, with karma/Jasmine for unit testing.

The script for running the tests: `karma start`.
The karma config is [here](https://github.com/ldeck/angular-webpack-starter-kit/blob/v5.1.1/karma.conf.js).
The webpack config is [here](https://github.com/ldeck/angular-webpack-starter-kit/blob/v5.1.1/webpack.config.js).

I keep getting these kinds of stack traces when there's an error:

```
    undefined
    assertArg
    assertArgFn
    annotate
    $$annotate
    injectionArgs
    instantiate
    $controller
    invoke
    workFn
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 10 (1 FAILED) (skipped 9) ERROR (0.01 secs / 0.008 secs)
```

This is obviously pretty useless other than letting me know something is undefined.

I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32625884/tracing-errors-using-karma-babel-webpack-with-bundles) but it didn't seem to work for me.

I've tried setting the devtool to either `eval`, `eval-source-map`, `inline-source-map`.

But I'm not getting a stack trace that points me to the file and line in question.

What might I be missing? 
Thanks!